# Как задать новый alias для сертификата Андроид приложение

Tags: android, android-studio, alias

Я давно опубликовал приложение в плей маркете. Сейчас хочу обновлять его.  У меня есть оригиналный сертификат от приложения. Я знаю пароли (key store password и key password) но не знаю alias. Хотя я использовал **keytool**, не помогло. Alias  текст было  в кириллицу и вот результат :

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вопрос: Как преобразовать этот текст(alias) на оригинальный текст или как менят alias на латинский текст?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте [так](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5707518/3212712) сменить алиас:

```
keytool -changealias -alias "тут_кириллица" -destalias "new-alias" -keypass keypass -keystore /path/to/keystore -storepass storepass
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Я восстановил алиас с помощью AndroidKeystoreBrute_v1.05 если интересно вот ссылка https://code.google.com/archive/p/android-keystore-password-recover/wikis/HowTo.wiki